# Load file in REPL is not working in Eclipse-counterclockwise

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I am a newbie to Clojure and Counterclockwise plugin for Eclipse. I can load the file into REPL for the first time. After that, If I make any changes to the code and try to load into REPL by commands (ctrl+alt+S) or by right-clicking and choosing the respective option, the files is not loading to the REPL.

For time being, I am restarting the REPL to load the changes. Is there any settings available for this to fix it? FYI, I am using eclipse Mars and Counterclockwise 0.34.0.STABLE001 plugin for eclipse.